# Fastest way to convert from vector of pairs to two independent vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector

lets say I have a `vector` of `pair<int,int>`. Now I want to extract the `pair.first` and `pair.second` as independent vectors. I can iterate on the vector and do that but is there a better/faster way?

Comment: I don't see any way of making it faster than loop over all items in the vector. You don't have to do the looping yourself though, use something like [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each).

Comment: Are you sure you need to copy the values into new vectors? Perhaps you could use [transform_iterators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) to simply iterate on the original vector while getting the pair elements, without copying them elsewhere.

Comment: yes. but I did not want to use boost. Anyways, everybody has given the correct answer so I will accept the answer with the best 'details'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C++11, if you don't need the old vector anymore, you could perhaps get a tiny bit of extra efficiency from move semantics:

```
for (auto it = std::make_move_iterator(v.begin()),
         end = std::make_move_iterator(v.end()); it != end; ++it)
{
    v1.push_back(std::move(it->first));
    v2.push_back(std::move(it->second));
}
```

Other than that, you certainly cannot do better than one loop. You will have to touch every element at least once, so this is as efficient as it gets.

Note that moving can only make a difference if the element types themselves have move semantics that are better than copying. This is not the case for `int`s, or any PODs. But it can't hurt to write your code generically so that you can take advantage of this in future situations.

If copying/moving is a problem, though, you should consider whether some view adapter for your original vector might be a better approach.

Comment: Whoa, never knew about `make_move_iterator`, +1

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Actually I doubt it's necessary here; I just put it in for fun (the `std::move` should already do the trick). The move iterator is very useful for algorithms, though. It comes pre-wrapped in [`algorithm/std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move), which is the moving version of `std::copy`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: And what would be the *extra efficiency* coming from? I don't think this is going to be any more efficient than the more idiomatic plain loop --which is also easier to reason about.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Only in the situation where the element types themselves take advantage of move semantics... Not for the OP's integers, that's true. I added a note about that. Cheers.

Comment: Just to note that at least for simple types, it's often faster to resize the destination (or create it the correct size to begin with) than to use `push_back`.  At least on some machines, with some implementations.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Certainly there should be a `reserve()` before the whole operation... `resize()` plus assignment trades zero-initialization against avoiding the `size` update; certainly worth profiling!

Comment: @KerrekSB If you construct the target vector with the correct size to begin with, or use `resize()`, there's no need for a `reserve()`.  Somewhat surprisingly (at least for me), with g++, `resize()` plus assignment beats `reserve()` plus `push_back()`, at least for the simple types.

Answer (score 3):

No there is not. The one thing to take care of is to use `reserve` on the two resulting vectors to prevent unnecessary reallocations.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to avoid the iteration.  As to the fastest solution,
it depends on what is in the pair, and on the actual implementation.
Depending on these, it may be better to create the target vectors with
the correct size, and assign to them; or to create them empty, and use
`reserve` and then `push_back`.  You might also want to compare indexing
with using iterators; if you're using pre-sized vectors, using only one
control variable instead of three might be an improvement.  (With g++,
the last time I measured, creating vectors of the correct size and 
assigning was faster than using `reserve` and `push_back`, at least for
`double`.  Despite the fact that it meant looping twice internally, and
initializing the values to `0.0`.)

You might also want to try creating functional objects to extract the
first and second elements of the pair (supposing you don't have them
already), and use two calls to `transform`.  Again, either with a
predimensionned vector or using a back inserter as target.  Off hand, I
wouldn't expect this to provide better performance, but you never know.

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over the vector anyway, so in terms of Complexity, this is as good as you can get.